# What spells or other effects cause weakness to a certain damage type?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-types, vulnerability

Are there any spells, items, or other effects that cause some form of susceptibility or vulnerability by damage type? I found Elemental Bane from the Elemental Evil companion, which adds an additional 2d6 damage to the first instance each turn of a selected damage type. Are there other ways to cause similar effects?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a "read the book" question. Except its "read every book."

Comment: @markovchain that is the definition of 'too broad' :)